# How to improve the search performance of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, in-memory-database, in-memory

I have stored almost 40 million tweets with their metadata on my machine which is quite powerful (Intel Core i7, 32 GB RAM, SSD). Any search queries on those tweets take too much time (as it is expected). So how can I improve the search performance in term of the elapsed time to retrieve search result? Does the usage of a fast in-memory database or data grid let the performance to be increased? How can I degrade the duration for search queries into seconds?

Comment: Please ad "da code". Your data structure, the indices you have and the queries you do. Without that, it is impossible  to say how to improve the performance for your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at something like sharding(horizontal scaling) in mongodb since you have huge amounts of data to process. For more info ([Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/sharding-introduction/))

> Sharding reduces the number of operations each shard handles. Each
>   shard processes fewer operations as the cluster grows. As a result, a
>   cluster can increase capacity and throughput horizontally.
>
> For example, to insert data, the application only needs to access the
>   shard responsible for that record.
>
> Sharding reduces the amount of data that each server needs to store.
>   Each shard stores less data as the cluster grows.
>
> For example, if a database has a 1 terabyte data set, and there are 4
>   shards, then each shard might hold only 256GB of data. If there are 40
>   shards, then each shard might hold only 25GB of data.

Comment: In which world are 40M * 240 huge? Thats 9,6GB. Lets say the metadata triples that. We are still way below what is to be considered huge.